# Autolayout Constraints Shifted in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am working on an app that uses a UICollectionView with cells that scroll vertically. I have set up the majority of the interface using AutoLayout. Here is the AutoLayout setup:

[image: AutoLayout]

However, the scroll does not produce the result I would like. Occasionally, the constraints get messed up and the `GradientView` and `TextView` appear disoriented.

This is what I expect to happen:

[image: Expectation]

This is what actually happens:

[image: Reality]

The purple in the background is the `Main Button`. The `Main Button` and `Shadow` are positioned correctly, but the `Gradient View` and `Text View` are not. The `Gradient View` and `Text View` have light gray and white background colors, respectively, and as shown, are not in the correct position.

I have tried updating the constraints in the `scrollViewDidScroll` and `cellWillDisplay` methods, but neither has had any effect.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    bigCollection.updateConstraints()
    for cell in bigCollection.visibleCells {
        cell.updateConstraints()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.updateConstraints()
}
```

What could be a possible cause of the constraints being changed while scrolling?

Comment: This question featured a video in a file locker, which has since been deleted. That makes the question less answerable, and it has been abandoned anyway, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

GradientView’s top, left, right will be zero (0) with your ‘mainButton’ and bottom of GradientView will be something like 30(as per your need) to TextView.
Same with your TextView. left, right, bottom will be 0 with your mainButton and Top will be 30 to GradientView.

Your GradientView and TextView constraints are set to main View thats why its happening. Can u plz try with my suggestions, and let me know?

Comment: What is the issue in this suggestion?